# Use fleqn with acm_proc?

Tags: amsmath, options, incompatibility, acm

I would like to use the fleqn option to amsmath package. However, my document class gets in the way:

Writing

```
 \documentclass[fleqn]{acm_proc_article-sp}
```

I am warned that the global option is ignored.
But, writing,

```
 \usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
```

I get an option clash warning.

Is there a way to go around this limitation? I suppose I could hack the class file, but I would prefer not to.

Comment: i know how to check a class file to see if an option is passed on to a package, but i don't know where to find this class file -- it's not on ctan or on the acm web site that i could find.  ???

Comment: @barbara beeton: you can find the document class here: http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/acm_proc_article-sp.cls/view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the `fleqn` option to the `amsmath` package before declaring the document class:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{fleqn}{amsmath}
\documentclass{acm_proc_article-sp}
```

Comment: also works for \documentclass{sig-alternate}